# Update null values when we use Addition assignment (+=)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
declare @temp table
(
    Id int,
    Qty int 
)

insert into @temp values(1,null)
update @temp set Qty+=2

select * from @temp
```

I am trying to update the `Qty` column however the `Qty` column is null by default. So because the production database column might be null when I try to update I am getting a null value I need `Qty` to be 2.

Comment: How do you want to get from `NULL` to `2`? You can't do arithmetic on NULL values.

Comment: Side note, `numeric(18,3)` seems like an odd data type choice for a quantity. When can you have `0.001` of something?

Comment: @Larnu There seem to be quite a few [units of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement) that could be reasonably subdivided, e.g. acre-feet of water. One of the SysGen parameters for VMS is specified in units of [μFornights](https://wiki.vmssoftware.com/Microfortnight). Sure, there isn't much of a market for 0.001 Widget, but would you bother bending over to pick up 0.001 Bitcoin from the sidewalk? (1 Bitcoin = USD 28,527.40 as I write this.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (or [`isnull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) to handle the null case.

```
update @temp set Qty = coalesce(Qty,0) + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment the value, then the column should not allow `NULL`s.

I would suggest that you default the value to `0`.  Then don't insert a `NULL` value explicitly:

```
declare @temp table (
    Id int,
    Qty int not null default 0
);

insert into @temp (id) values (1);
update @temp set Qty += 2;

select * from @temp;
```

You can also express the `insert` as:

```
insert into @temp (id, value) values (1, default);
```